# Help to see if my claim is correct dealing with cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

For every integer n, show Dn has a subgroup of order 4.

We know Dn is a cyclic group of order n. I claim H=. We can rotate by 1/n th the way around. |H|=|R|=n. H is a cyclic subgroup of order n. And this is a contradiction. So, |Dn|=2n

How does this prove Dn is a subgroup of order 4?

Comment: H = < R >      correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few bugs with the claim to begin with.  (a) $D_n$ only makes sense for positive integers $n$.  (b) $D_n$, for odd $n$, cannot have a subgroup of order $4$ since it would violate [Lagrange's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29).

So the claim could only possibly be true for even $n \geq 2$.

If $n=2m$ for odd $m$, then "rotate by $\tfrac{n}{4}$" (not $\tfrac{1}{n}$-th) is not actually possible (since $m$ is not divisible by $2$).  It will, however, have a subgroup isomorphic to $D_2$ which has order $4$ (combine "rotate by $\tfrac{n}{2}$" with "flip").

If $n=4m$ for $m \geq 1$, then the element whose action defines "rotate by $\tfrac{n}{4}$" exists, and consequently it will indeed generate a cyclic subgroup of order $4$.